# How to distinguish between the reasons Firebase Transactions return null?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

From my understanding of Transactions, it can return `null` for two reasons:

1. There is actually no value at the node where the transaction is being performed.
2. The local cache is empty as Firebase Cloud Functions is stateless. Therefore, it may return `null` the very first time and it will re-run the function.

My question is, how do we distinguish between these two cases? Or does firebase do the distinction by itself?

```
Myref.transaction(function(currentData) {
    if(currentData != null) {
        return currentData + 1;
    } else {
        console.log("Got null")
        return;
    }
}, function(error, committed, snapshot) {
    if(!committed) {
        // The transaction returned null. 
        // But don't know if it's  because the node is null or 
        // because the transaction failed during the first iteration.
    }
});
```

In the above example, the transaction callback will be passed `null` both when the value at `Myref` is non-existent **and** when it attempts to get the data in the very first try when executing the transaction.

If the value of `Myref` is actually empty, I want the number `1238484` to be filled in there. If it is not, and the `null` is actually being thrown because of a wrong read by the transaction, how do I make this distinction?

PS: Please don't suggest a listener at the node. Is there any other more effective way of doing this?

Comment: What is the specific problem you're trying to solve with a transaction?

Comment: This is for the sake of a better understanding of transactions. I've simplified the example now. With the code that I've written, I want the transaction to be aborted if there is no value at the node. But the problem is that it gets aborted even if there is a value at the node due to the nature of transactions itself.

Comment: Are you verifying that node.exists() returns true,  as this will help you to determine if it's the node exists, therefor you are not calling it on a null place.

Comment: In my PS, I've asked for a way other than checking if node.exists().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On initial run of the transaction and value returned from the update function is `undefined`, [`onComplete` is invoked with error to be `null`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/v4.5.1/packages/database/src/core/Repo_transaction.ts#L203)

For subsequent runs when there is no data, [a reason for aborting the transaction is provided](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/v4.5.1/packages/database/src/core/Repo_transaction.ts#L573).

You can check the value of error to differentiate whether there is no data at the reference or local cache is empty.

```
error === null && !committed // local cache is empty
error !== null && !committed // there is no data
```

This is internal implementation detail and you shouldn't rely on it for your queries.

Comment: So what would you do if there is actually data in the database ref but it still returns null in first run as you said ?, how can I overcome this issue? I receive null from the transcation but it is not supposed to return null I assume it is happening because of the local cache thingy that you mentioned